# Android: Set a Time out for AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

We know AsyncTask is used in Android for short time background process. Generally we using for WepApi parsing, In Some time "**`doInBackground()`**" execute for a long time for getting the response.

Suppose at the time of execution of **`doInBackground`** if our internet is gone , the progress bar still working to getting the result.

So my question is can we set a TIMEOUT  for the **`doInBackground`** execution like if it execute more than 2 min stop the **`doInBackground`** execution and call **`onPostExecute`**.

i tryed this method in **`doInBackground`** call

```
 protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String request = String.format(params[0], "12");
        Log.e("Tag " ,"Pasing Start");
        replay= getResponseByParsing(URL);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Checking async task",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, 20000);
```

but the application going to forcefully close

what will be the good solution for set a TIMEOUT **`doInBackground`** exection

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: I prefer the retrofit for webapi it is fast and do all the functionality internally   http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @Nithinlal. here I am facing the problem like if internet is gone at the time of AsyncTask exection then what will do

Comment: I'd also recommend using something like http://square.github.io/okhttp/ or retrofit mentioned above. You'd just set client.`setConnectTimeout()` and `client.setReadTimeout()` and be done with it.

Comment: you cannot use Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Checking async task",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); within doInbackground Method. you can use onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute(). to Toast. This is why your app forcefully closed.

Comment: i can suggest a workaround, you can use that `handler` inside `Activity or `Fragment` from where you are calling `AsyncTask` and in the `run` method of `Handler` `cancel AsyncTask` like this 'AsyncTask.cancel()'..

Comment: @BinilSurendran: Why you want to set timeout for `doInBackground` ?? my suggestion is just set timeout for HTTP request and check network connection before making any request.

Comment: You can use **Volley**

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K  Thanks its working

Answer (score 0):

First execute your AsyncTask, then schedule [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) after 2 min.

When timer hits, check [AsyncTask Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html).

If it's in `RUNNING` state, then [Cancel AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) by `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`.

Just check `isCancelled()` once in a while like below:

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

**Note:** Calling `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` method will result in `onCancelled(Object)` being invoked on the UI thread after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. Calling this method guarantees that `onPostExecute(Object)` is never invoked. After invoking this method, you should check the value returned by `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])` to finish the task as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
private void startTimer() {
        mTimer1 = new Timer();
        mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        if (count == 120) { // check for two minutes
                            // cancel your asynctask here
                            // cancel your timer also
                            mTimer1.cancel();
                        } else {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        // start your async task here
        mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 1, 1000); // at the same time start timer also.
    }
```

Happy Coding.!!